# UPS developer API missing ja

Tags: api, jar, ups

I am looking for what jar library to import into my software. I am using ups's Shipping_Pkg_Gnd.zip for a spring board to provide shipping label generation. However they did not provide a .jar library in any of sample code that they provide. Does anyone know where to get this library.

Here are the imports that will not work because I do not have the required developer API
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipmentErrorMessage;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.BillShipperType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.InternationalFormType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.LabelImageFormatType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.LabelSpecificationType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.PackageType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.PackageWeightType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.PackagingType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.PaymentInfoType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ProductType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ProductWeightType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.RequestType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ServiceAccessToken_type0;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ServiceType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ShipAddressType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ShipFromType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ShipPhoneType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ShipToAddressType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ShipToType;
import com.ups.www.wsdl.xoltws.ship.v1_1.ShipServiceStub.ShipUnitOfMeasurementType;

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue, and the solution is to use wsimport.sh to generate the jar/class files from the wsdl.

So you have to copy the following six files to the same folder

```
$ mkdir ups_ship && cd ups_ship
$ ls -1
common.xsd
Error1.1.xsd
IFWS.xsd
ShipWebServiceSchema.xsd
Ship.wsdl
UPSSecurity.xsd
$ wsimport.sh -verbose -keep -extension -target 2.0 Ship.wsdl
```

Generated code:

```
$ ls -1 com/ups/wsdl/xoltws/ship/v1/
ShipAcceptErrorMessage.class
ShipAcceptErrorMessage.java
ShipConfirmErrorMessage.class
ShipConfirmErrorMessage.java
ShipmentErrorMessage.class
ShipmentErrorMessage.java
ShipPortType.class
ShipPortType.java
ShipService.class
ShipService.java
```

Now you can put all your *.class files in a package and use it in your project:

```
$jar cvf com_ups_wsdl_xoltws_ship_v1.jar ./com/ups/wsdl/xoltws/ship/v1/*.class
```

Your new jar:

```
$jar tf com_ups_wsdl_xoltws_ship_v1.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/ups/wsdl/xoltws/ship/v1/ShipAcceptErrorMessage.class
com/ups/wsdl/xoltws/ship/v1/ShipConfirmErrorMessage.class
com/ups/wsdl/xoltws/ship/v1/ShipmentErrorMessage.class
com/ups/wsdl/xoltws/ship/v1/ShipPortType.class
com/ups/wsdl/xoltws/ship/v1/ShipService.class
```